# usage of NToastNotify package in .NetCore package raises the following glitch

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, code-generation

Has anybody worked with `NToastNotify` package in any .Net Core project? This is a descriptive question from me. I followed the instructions enlisted here (for Noty, please read the documented instructions for Noty) - https://github.com/nabinked/NToastNotify

The errors I get -

> The type or namespace name 'IToastNotification' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'NToastNotify' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

in the concerned spaces where the package was tried to be implemented.

For example, in the controller

```cs
private readonly IToastNotification _toastNotification;

public AccountsController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IToastNotification toastNotification, SignInManager<AppUser> signInM, ILogger<AccountsController> logger, ApplicationDbContext appDbContext)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _signInManager = signInM;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    _toastNotification = toastNotification;
}
```

Any idea what could  be the issue? I was also getting conflicts with `CodeGeneration.Design` package. So uninstalled and reinstalled it. Did it a clean and rebuild of the project. This doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Worth mentioning, project is in .Net Core 2.2. Could that be the trouble? Version conflict? Pointers, where to start from to rectify this.

Comment: **are you missing a using directive**?

Comment: how about targeting to `net core 3.1`, then rebuild your project?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT  -- will try that. something closely suggested by answer below as well.

I Want To Know, reason to downvote the question. specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Worth mentioning, project is in .Net Core 2.2. Could that be the
> trouble? Version conflict? Pointers, where to start from to rectify
> this.

Yes, this is the version conflict.

If you are using .net core 3.0 over version, you can install the newest version of NToastNotify package.

To solve it in your current project, you need to download the `NToastNotify package` whose version should `lower than 6.0.1`, which means that you can only download packages `up to version 5.0.12` to adapt to `.net core 2.2`.

[image]

Comment: so v5.0.12 should be compatible ure saying,

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury, yes.If my answer helped you solve your issue, please accept it as the answer.